# Can You Access the Excel VBE Selection Programatically?

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

If I have some VB Component open in the Excel VBE, with some text highlighted as shown,

[image]

Is there a way to programmatically grab the text 
"zBool"?

Preferrably NOT using Sendkeys

6x New Zealand Steinlager Beers (a good solution), for another good solution

Q: Why do black sheep eat less than white sheep?

A: Because there aren't as many of them

Comment: What do you mean by "grabbing the text"? Do you want to see the current value in zBool while you're running the code? Trying to copy something to a cell? Or did you already resort to the beers?

Comment: No, I'd like to get the literal text "zBool", or whatever text is currently highlighted in the active VBE Window. Perhaps with some code like StringVar=GetCurrentlyHighlightedVBEText()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a reference to "Microsoft visual basic for applications extensibility..."

```
Sub Tester()

Dim oVBE As vbe
Dim startLine As Long, startCol As Long
Dim endLine As Long, endCol As Long
Dim sContent As String, tmp As String, l As Long
    Set oVBE = Application.vbe

    oVBE.ActiveCodePane.GetSelection _
        startLine, startCol, endLine, endCol

    For l = startLine To endLine
        tmp = oVBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.Lines(l, 1)
        If l = endLine Then tmp = Left(tmp, endCol - 1)
        If l = startLine Then tmp = Right(tmp, (Len(tmp) - startCol) + 1)
        sContent = sContent & IIf(Len(sContent) > 0, Chr(10), "") & _
                  tmp
    Next l


    Debug.Print sContent

End Sub
```

GetSelection method: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443954(v=vs.60).aspx

See here for how to use that returned information to access the actual text:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx  (I'm sure it's there somewhere...)

**EDIT** - did that for you for my own education...
I'll put it on your tab ;-)

Comment: Thanks Tim, much appreicated. I'm looking to use this as a way to access Code Documentation for a Project from within the Project, with the Documentation also embedded in the Project (if that makes sense)